# jQuery .click() runs only once

Tags: jquery

For some reason I do not understand this feature, runs well, but the function click() it runs only once.

```
$('#type').change(function() {
    alert('ok');
    $('#choixfiche').click();
});
```

What do I correct it?

Comment: Change the element `#type` more than once...?

Comment: It only runs once because you're tirggering it only once (per change of `#type`). What did you expect it to do?

Comment: You call `click` only once, what do you expect?

Comment: I think I misspoke.
I was talking about that when I change my select for the first time, click the function starts fine and well.
But again when I select a field in my select for the second time, it is no longer running.

Answer (score 14):

```
$('#type').change(function() {
    alert('ok');
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
    $('#choixfiche').click();
});
```

Comment: Use PHP to generate the multiple calls!

Comment: Thats a great answer, I upvoted it as now atleast it clicks ten times :-)

Comment: I think I misspoke.
I was talking about that when I change my select for the first time, click the function starts fine and well.
But again when I select a field in my select for the second time, it is no longer running.

Comment: Are you actually changing the value of the dropdown or just selecting the same one again? The `change` function is only called when the value has changed.

Comment: I change anything of value.
I know he goes into the function as the alert is displayed, but the function click() it is no longer running.

Comment: What does the click function do? Try putting the alert on the click function? Can you post a jsFiddle of your HTML and JS code?

Comment: I discovered this morning that the problem was fancybox.
So the famous window fancybox starts up the first time.

I adapted as I have the jsfiddle.

Necessarily the jsfiddle it works perfectly the way I want and it does not work locally once.

Here's the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Architecte/rk2YR/7/

Comment: OK I've found it.
it was necessary that I turn off virtually any javascript in my fancybox, because they took the place of elders who had been called before.
Thank you for your help